# Github - Allow Users To Open A Issue From My Github Page?

Tags: json, github

How do I go about letting users open an issues from my Github page itself?

So I want it to work like users goes on my site http://example.github.io/ and click a button that says something like "Open an Issue" and have it take them to a form well sill on my site and once they submit it, it opens a issues with the info they entered.

Comment: SO is about people with problem with code

Comment: I want to know if somehow I can do this with somehow with code?

Comment: Unless you've already made an attempt to implement this yourself (and have a [mcve] of any problem code you're running into), this is probably more suited as a question for GitHub support instead.

Answer (score 0):

One approach, [described here](https://gist.github.com/bmcbride/62600e48274961819084), is to:

- redirect the user to a [Google Form](https://www.google.com/forms/about/)
- use [App Script automation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/)
- call in that script the GitHub API to [create an issue](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue) (`POST /repos/:owner/:repo/issues`)

For instance:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {

  var itemResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();
  var item1 = itemResponses[1].getResponse();
  var item2 = itemResponses[2].getResponse();
  var item3 = itemResponses[3].getResponse();
  var item4 = itemResponses[4].getResponse();
  var item5 = itemResponses[5].getResponse();
  var item6 = itemResponses[6].getResponse();
  var item7 = itemResponses[7].getResponse();
  var item8 = itemResponses[8].getResponse();

  var title = "Bug: " + item2;

  var body = 
      "<strong>Submitted By: </strong>" + item1 +
        "\n<strong>url: </strong>" + item3 +
        "\n<strong>device: </strong>" + item4 +
        "\n<strong>browser: </strong>" + item5 +
        "\n<strong>expected behavior: </strong>" + item6 +
        "\n<strong>actual behavior: </strong>" + item7 +
        "\n<strong>steps to reproduce: </strong>" + item8;

  var payload = {
    "title": title,
    "body": body
  };

  var options = {
    "method": "POST",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "payload": JSON.stringify(payload)
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.github.com/repos/EXAMPLE?access_token="+ghToken, options);
}
```